# Java (latest version) Lambda: replace anonymous inner class by lambda

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, lambda, java-8

I have got a class which contains the following:

```
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            // creating font object and store textarea value font
            Font font = area.getFont();
            // setting size from getting slider value
            float size = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
            // setting font size for textarea
            area.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));

        }
    });
```

VScode Insider tells me to replace the inner class with lambda,

Here is a screenshot if you want to see what I mean,
[ChangeListener is underline as yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlEYG.png)

So I tried to think of ways and couldn't come up with any since I am not experienced enough, any one want to help me find other ways how to write this "ChangeListener" please...?

Comment: If you click where it says "Quick Fix", doesn't it give you an option to do it automatically?

Comment: It doesn't, that's the problem...

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft should not be making IDEs.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Intellij IDEA it will do it for you.

```
slider.addChangeListener(e -> {
            // creating font object and store textarea value font
            Font font = area.getFont();
            // setting size from getting slider value
            float size = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
            // setting font size for textarea
            area.setFont(font.deriveFont(size));
    });
```

Comment: I uses this solution and it work on vscode...

Answer (score 0):

I never like these long lambda methods. I prefer something like:

private void processSliderEvent(ChangeEvent ce) {
...
}

slider.addChangeListener(this::processSliderEvent);

Comment: I understand though